# Simple probability problem using ML/Neural Networks

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

Trying to get a probability of success for a dataset like this:

```
[
    { input: { sections: 99, duration: 10, defects: 5 }, output: { success: 1 } },
    { input: { sections: 2000, duration: 30, defects: 50 }, output: { success: 1 } },
    { input: { sections: 50, duration: 10, defects: 5 }, output: { success: 0 } },
    { input: { sections: 500, duration: 20, defects: 15 }, output: { success: 0 } },
    { input: { sections: 990, duration: 100, defects: 50 }, output: { success: 1 } },

  ]
```

Not sure what the best tool for the job is or how to get started with this. Tinkered a bit with brain.js but my lack of knowledge on the subject is holding me back. I got a desired output but the configuration used is obviously wrong cause it took 30sec to output a result for this dataset, maybe that's normal, don't know.

What's the best tool for this job? Preferably for JS, but all ideas are welcomed.

A code sample of a first attempt with brain.js. The config is probably all wrong for my use case but like i mentioned, complete noob when it comes to this

```
const brain=require('brain.js');
const config={
    inputSize: 20,
    inputRange: 20,
    hiddenLayers: [20, 20],
    outputSize: 20,
    learningRate: 0.01,
    decayRate: 0.999,
};
let learnt;

try {
  learnt = require('./trained_net.json');
} catch(err) {
  console.log('No previous training data.');
}

const net = new brain.recurrent.RNN(config);

if(learnt){
  net.fromJSON(learnt);
}

net.train([
    { input: [99, 10, 5], output: [1] },
    { input: [150, 10, 15], output: [0] },
    { input: [99, 10, 25], output: [0] },
    { input: [990, 30, 5], output: [1] },
    { input: [990, 100, 500], output: [0] },
  ], { log:true, iterations:50, keepNetworkIntact:true });

const fs = require('fs');
const run = JSON.stringify(net.toJSON());
fs.writeFileSync('trained_net.json',run);

const output = net.run([100, 10, 6]);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: how large is your training dataset?

Comment: Tried a couple of sets ranging from 50 elements to 1000

Comment: 1000 element sounds good as a training dataset.  30 seconds sounds plausible, depending how many epohs you've set for the training.    You need to show your code to see what's going on.   Typically people try several methods, Decision Trees, SVN, Neural networks and compare performance before deciding on a model.    In any case if you have good performance say 90% then you're good to go, or did you have other requirements?

Comment: Added a code sample to the question, if that helps

Comment: I don't think an RNN is the best choice for your data, try a feed forward.  Also let me know the performance e.g. accuracy of your model.   Look at this example https://scrimba.com/scrim/c36zkcb.   How to create a feed forward model and measure the accuracy.

Comment: On one of the experiments i tried the feedForward (brain.NeuralNetwork) but even on a 1:1 query it returned bogus results. For example, on the example dataset, if i asked it to give a result for `{ input: [99, 10, 5]}` it would return something like 0.3548... Again, it' probably a config issue

Comment: it will always return values between 0 and .99  is up to you to set the threshold.  I think 0.9 should be fine as 1 anything else is a 0.  In the example I linked to it they round the results using Math.round and then they can compare to the original expected output